# StringUTF16 публичные методы в package-private классе

Tags: java

Зачем в `package-private` классе `StringUTF16` делать публичные методы, если вне пакета к этому классу, а следовательно и к методам, всё равно нет доступа?

Comment: раз класс final, значит он утилитарный, раз package-private, то использование его предусмотрено только в этом пакете, если методы сделать не public, то как его использовать ?!

Comment: @keekkenen я просто ничего не буду отвечать, чтобы вы сами подумали над тем, что вы сейчас сказали.

Comment: возможно, стоит переформулировать вопрос, чтобы получить более внятный ответ

Comment: @keekkenen возможно, `package-private` методы можно использовать в `package-private` классе внутри пакета.

Answer (score 0):

Если данный класс не отмечен `final`, то смысл есть, т.к. расширять можно в другом `package` и там данные методы не будут видны.

Но т.к. `StringUTF16` помечен `final` то какой-то технической пользы это не несёт, может только помочь выделить наиболее важные методы взаимодействия с данным классом.

Comment: `package-private` классы расширять тоже нельзя. С ними ничего нельзя сделать из другого пакета.

Comment: ну, не совсем, можно в этом же пакете определить `public` класс, который унаследован от `package-private` и затем от него унаследовать, костыльно конечно, но будет работать

Comment: Ну так это должна быть задумка человека, пишущего `package-private` класс. У меня то нет доступа к этому пакету.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия дуступ к пакету всегда есть, создайте у себя такой же пакет

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну, например, `JDK` я изменить не могу. Скопировать один класс я тоже не могу, потому что он использует другие непубличные классы. Предлагаете мне скопировать весь пакет? Или скопировать некоторые методы? Так вопрос стоял не в этом. Если автор класса не задумывал, что данный класс будут наследовать, то он не будет делать ещё один публичный класс, причём пустой, который наследует данный.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия я только про то что Вы в своем коде можете добавить любой пакет, в том числе и идентичный пакету, в котором лежит класс, который Вы хотите расширить, даже если он package-private в таком случае расширить его можно, к вопросу это мало относится т.к. там класс final